# How to authenticate a facebook user after closing browser PHP sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

This might be a really stupid question but I'm a bit confused. After a user has allowed permission to my app is it still necessary to have the user click the Facebook->getLoginUrlURL after every time they close and re-open their browser?

The $Facebook->getUser(); function does not return the facebook user automatically after re-opening the web browser. Is there some way of avoiding having to go the login url again?

Or is this simply the way the process works and I'll still need to set cookies for future identification?

Comment: Use the JS SDK, it can recognize the user automatically.

Comment: Right, well, I'm mainly only using the users Facebook details for a quick registration, inserting the fbid and email. But all site actions are based on sessions that contain the local user id, not the facebook users id.

So all I'm really using FB for is to retrieve the users facebook id so I can associate it with a user id.

So it would probably just make more sense to store a cookie to identify the user, and when it expires just have them click the fb link to login again?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the user's login status using the Facebook SDK.

Specifically, you can check whether or not they are logged into Facebook and whether or not they have previously logged into your app.

Per the Facebook documentation you can do this a couple of different ways:

1. Set status: true when you initialize the SDK and subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange event
2. Specifically call the FB.getLoginStatus function.

Response Object: 
{
   status: 'connected',
   authResponse: {
        accessToken: '...',
        expiresIn: '...', 
        signedRequest:'....',
        userID:'...'
    }
}

Here's the link to Facebook's documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/#checklogin